# Add Music to iOS programmatically

Tags: ios

Let say I want to create an iOS app that download music files from the internet.

Is it possible then to put this music files on the Music Library so that I can play it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not possible. The only way to add music to your library is through iTunes or through the iTunes Store app. Even if you did find a way, it'd probably be through some private API and you'd probably get rejected on the app store.

Comment: So, do you know any private API to access it?

Comment: @Henry: Please refer to my answer for private API: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12840618/add-music-to-ios-programmatically/24256847#24256847

Answer (score 1):

As Simon said, you won't get music into the native music library.  You could however store the audio files and use the AVFoundation Framework (AVAudioPlayer class) to replay them.  You could also possibbly use the AudioToolbox framework.  Problem is you would have to implement your own music library and your own playback functionality.

Did I mention you have roughly a 0% chance of this app making it into the app store?

It is clearly possible though...even trivial...

Answer (score 0):

Well, in terms of possibility, it is possible if you jailbreak your device, you'd need 2 tweaks to do it:

"Safari download enabler" or manager: to allow you to download files.
"Bride": allows you to import downloaded or saved mp3 files or mp4 video files to your iOS library.

I've been using it for a while and it works like magic

Answer (score 0):

You can have private API/Library. Though I never tried, but you can.

Here is the another similar post:

[Programmatically add content to music library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13147044/programmatically-add-content-to-music-library)