# Programmatically add content to music library

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, audio, export

I have an application developed that stores certain sounds in its Documents directory.
Is it possible to export or store these sounds to user's iPod library? They are in .caf format if important.

Comment: Did you use the libipodimport to get this working, or find another way?

Comment: Did not get this working yet. It needs to work on non jailbroken devices.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is only possible if the app is for jailbroken devices. In this case, you can use my [libipodimport](http://github.com/H2CO3/libipodimport) library for importing music and audio files to the iPod media library.

If the app is distributed via the AppStore, then it's unfortunately not possible, through you can still try to use a private API: the `SSDownload`, `SSDownloadQueue` and `SSDownloadMetadata` classes ([class-dumped headers here](http://developer.limneos.net/?framework=StoreServices.framework&header=SSDownload.h)) from the `StoreServices` private framework enable it - you *might* be able to get through the AppStore using these **if you manage to hide them,** but **it's highly unlikely.**

Comment: I just came across your answer, and I tried your library (Added the AppSupport and StoreServices headers and frameworks), but it doesn't seem to do anything. I have lots of warnings in the server.m file though : - Receiver 'SSDownloadMetadata' is a forward class and corresponding @interface may not exist', - Instance method '-setCopyright' not found... etc.. Can you please tell me what i'm missing ? Thank you very much

Comment: @H2CO3 I also find it hard to use your library. There are many header files link to each other, that would be great if you can develop a sample project, so that we can learn from it without asking you much. I appreciate your helps.

Comment: @VibolTeav Many header files to link? What do you mean by that? One does not link header files. They are not even compiled. But anyway, the Makefile does the job, provided you set up the proper path to the iOS SDK on the first line. Also, 1. the library is in Cydia, you don't have to compile it; 2. have you looked at the README file? It can be used by writing some 3 (yes, three) lines of code. That should not be hard. If you find it so, I suggest you take a step back and learn the basic concepts of C and Objective-C programming and compilation.