# iOS: Add audio file to audio library

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, ios5, audio

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Programmatically add content to music library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13147044/programmatically-add-content-to-music-library)

Is it possible to store an audio file, which was recorded within my app, to the iOS audio library?
I checked the documentation but all I found are means to access the libary but not add new audio files.

**EDIT**: with library I refere to the music library which is for instance opened when using the `MPMediaPickerController`

Regards,

Comment: what is `iOS Audio Library` ?

Comment: I mean the library where you can find the playlists, albums, etc.

Comment: If you mean Music (former iPod) not ! because MPMediaPickerController could access to the Music library